# how to remove six.reraise in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, six

I have some Python legacy code that looks like this:

```py
except ValueError as e:
    new = DecodingError(
        "Failed to decode value {!r} for field {}, got: {}".format(
            raw_value, field_name, e
        )
    )
    six.reraise(DecodingError, new, sys.exc_info()[2])
```

Everything is on Python 3 so I don't need `six` anymore and would like to remove that dependency. But I don't understand what `reraise` does and how I can replace it with native Python 3 syntax. I don't find [the explanation in the docs](https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.reraise) to be much help.

What should I replace `six.reraise(...)` with in Python 3?

Comment: `raise new from e`

Comment: https://github.com/benjaminp/six/blob/7783c9e983b1fa37299a1db5c9e116462cbb53b8/six.py#L713